# What is better for asp.net mvc site sessions or cookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

what is better for asp.net mvc site for users login and maybe some wizard status saving sessions or cookies, and what is safer?

Answer (score 2):

A cookie is sent to the client and *could* be manipulated. A Session value stays at the server, so no client can forge it.

Comment: Well, most of the time a session IS a coopie (in that it is assocaited with a sessnion duration cookie on the client to find out which session to use).

Comment: The session is *identified* by a cookie, the *values* are stored only on the server.

Comment: Yes, buti t means that at the end "has to work without cookies" etc. requires more work. There still is a cookie involved normally.